# Regex to identify file pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a folder with files coming in as

```
fileName(prefix) + " " + todayDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv";
```

For simple file my regex was `FilePrefix + @"(.*)\.csv"`

How to have a search pattern to get file for only today's date ?

Comment: You're going to have to stuff today's date into the Regex. Where is the code that consumes this Regex now?

Comment: Specifically today's date or just date?

Comment: If you want today's date: Specifically today's date. Luckily you can just build a regex on-the-fly that will handle a new date every day.

Comment: Since you have all the relevant details included, you don't need a Regex anymore, just construct the string, no??

Comment: This doesn't seem like it needs a regex since you're matching against an exact string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like if you're just searching for today's date, then you should already know exactly what file name you're looking for.  So there's no need for a regex - just look for files where

```
var expectedName = FilePrefix + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv"; 

String.Compare(fileName, expectedName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this

```
List<string> fileNames = // wherever you're getting these

var ending = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv";

var filteredFileNames = fileNames.Where(x => x.EndsWith(ending));
```